# How can i change icon color of bootstrap v2.2.2?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-2

I am using Bootstrap  v2.2.2 in my application, I used ‘icon-off’ class to a span. By default it is showing with dark gray colored icon. I want to change this icon color into red and blue. I used ‘text-error’  class for red colored icon,  I am unable get that icon into red and I have not found a class for blue color and how can I blink this red colored icon?

Here is my code,

```
<span class="icon-off text-error" title="shutdown"></span> | <span class="icon-off text-blue" title="Active"></span>
```

Please help me some one with this, how can I add color to icons using bootstrap classes or CSS?

NOTE: Bootstrap 3.0.0, font-awesome not recommended to my current project, so I should not upgrade to other versions.

Answer (score 2):

Own answering to my question, Because it may helpful to some one.
But, I am not sure why 'icon-off' not displaying with user defined color code.I used 'icon-switch' instead of 'icon-off'.

below is my working code,

```
<span class="icon-switch text-error" title="shutdown"></span>
<span class="icon-off" style="color:blue" title="Active"></span>
```